# How to use "user logged in" as an access argument for a MENU_CALLBACK?

Tags: users, routes

I would like to require that users be logged in to access a particular MENU_CALLBACK.

The following works, but only for the admin account.  Regular users are still denied access:

```
'access arguments' => array('user_is_logged_in')
```

There must be an access argument that just checks for authenticated users?

Comment: If there is no way to do this, I will be creating my own permission using hook_permission() and assigning authenticated users that permission.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`access arguments` is for the arguments that will be passed to the callback function...you need to use `access callback` instead:

```
'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in'
```

Since `user_is_logged_in()` doesn't take any arguments, you can safely remove `access arguments` for your menu item.

Your current code works for the admin account only because the default [`access callback`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_access/7) is `user_access()`, which bypasses the access check for user 1.

Comment: The opposite then is `'access callback' => 'user_is_anonymous'`.

Comment: For Drupal 8 under "requirements" in your YAML file, add this:  _role: 'authenticated'